# text File I/O and Regular Expressions

Tags: java

- so my objective is to create a class that Reads the name of a file to
  create as the first command line argument. (Overwrite any file with
  the same name).
- I am then supposed to read an integer value as the second command
  line argument.
- The  program  should  generate as  many random numbers as  are 
  specified  in  the  second  command  line  argument with  magnitudes 
  between 1  and 1000  and  write  them  to  the  file.
- The last step to finishing the program is that You must write only 5
  numbers on each line and then begin a new line. (The last line may 
  have  less  than  5  numbers.)  Delimit  the  numbers  on  a  line 
  with  the  &character.  The  end  of  a  line  should  be  delimited 
  by  the  #character.  No  other  delimiters should be explicitly
  used.

this is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class RandomNumGen{
static final int SEED=152;
public static void fileStore( String file, int number )
{        
    if (file == null || number <=0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error");
    }

    String line = "%s&%s&%s&%s&%s#\n";
    BufferedWriter buffWriter = null;
    Random rand = new Random(SEED);

    try{
        buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        int x = number / 5;
        int j = number - x * 5;
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            int number1 = rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1;
            int number2 = rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1;
            int number3 = rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1;
            int number4 = rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1;
            int number5 = rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1;
            String str = String.format(line,number1,number2,number3,number4,number5);

            buffWriter.write(str);
            System.out.println(str);

        }

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
        {
            str.append(rand.nextInt(1000-1+1)+1);
            str.append("&");

        }
        str.deleteCharAt(str.length()-1);
        str.append("#");
        String lineStr = str.toString();
        buffWriter.write(lineStr);

        System.out.print(lineStr);

        buffWriter.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    fileStore("output.txt",14);
}
}
```

my program seems to work fine however when I use an int that ends in 5 or 0 
I get an java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of
range: -1.

this is my output:

```
286&112&602&201&763#

318&820&768&787&897#

707&54&927&40#
```

any tips for improving my code would be great.

Comment: this `for (int i=0; i<j; i++)` will not be entered into so `str` (the StringBuilder) will be empty

Comment: what should i do to change it?

Comment: I would change your program so that it first generates `number` amount of random values and stores then in a `List`, then iterate through the List and print each one, after each `five` elements print a NewLine

Comment: What is the idea of `rand.nextInt (1000-1+1)+1`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using a format isn't a bad idea, but I would say KISS:

```
    try{
        BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++)
        {
            int n = rand.nextInt (1000) + 1;
            if (i % 5 == 4 || i == number-1)
                str.append (n + "#\n");
            else
                str.append (n + "&");
        }
        String lineStr = str.toString();
        buffWriter.write (lineStr);
        System.out.print (lineStr);
        buffWriter.close ();
    }
```

For counting from 0

```
(i % 5 == 4 || i == number-1)
```

This will be true for the last element of each line and for the very last number.

Comment: You need to use try-with-resources if you want to leave out a catch and finally block.

Comment: It's just the fragment, where I made changes - I don't have a main method too, which seems not to be the question of Kyle Lynch. I just pulled the declaration of the buffWriter inside the try-block, because it isn't used outside.